# ARM Mac - unable to run react-native run-ios

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

I ran following commands to create a project

`react-native init test`

`cd iOS`

`pod install`

later from project home directory

`react-native run-ios`

I get following error

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
     CompileC /Users/sp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-ausxdgmizfvufjajqpwlgewxxhww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DistributedMutex.o /Users/sp/Documents/GitHub/Self/test/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

need help resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

xCode 12.5 is the problem here. It seems to break react-native builds. Solutions are mentioned here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-830184757

looks like you're on react-native 0.64

1. update `podfile` to use

```rb
use_flipper!('Flipper' => '0.75.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3')
```

2. update `package.json` to use

```json
"react-native": "facebook/react-native#cf8a364767df830d7255339741350bb53ab1a68a"
```

---

If that does not work,

1. remove `use_flipper!` from your `podfile` (disables flipper)
2. run `pod install`
3. clean and rebuild

Comment: Looks like it doesn't related ARM Mac, but Mac OS itself. It is appear after last Mac OS update